# Difference between "tranche" and "batch"

Tags: word-choice

I work in the data science, where we tend to use "batch" to refer to collections of data points composed as follows:

```
Biosamples 1-10, processed as per A, on Day 1 = batch 1
Biosamples 11-20, processed as per A, on Day 2 = batch 2
Biosamples 21-30, processed as per A, on Day 3 = batch 3
```

We're now working with another institution and will be combining data between the two. The data are inherently different (DNA sequencing depth, experimental platform etc.).

```
Biosamples 1-10, processed as per A, at location 1
Biosamples 11-20, processed as per B, at location 2
```

Is "batch" still the most appropriate term? I've seen "tranche" used in finance but wondering if "tranche" MUST be finance.

p.s. I don't think "treatment" is appropriate because it's not the same samples treated in two different ways

Comment: In finance, *tranches* are always stratified. Typically by seniority  of debt. I do not see any stratification (vertical ordering or hierarchy) in your examples.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in a dictionary?  If not, why not?  The two dictionaries I've looked at refer to *tranche* primarily for financial purposes.  See [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/tranche) & [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tranche).

Comment: I've seen "tranche" used in the context of product/software testing, where its meaning is synonymous with set or batch. eg https://www.accc.gov.au/publications/accc-aer-annual-report/accc-aer-annual-report-2013-14/accc-and-aer-annual-report-2013-14/part-3-performance-program-11-accc/goal-2-protect-the-interests-and-safety-of-consumers-and-support-fair-trading-in-markets/23-protect-consumers-from-unsafe-products *" Five articles from the first tranche of testing were above the acceptable limit, a result we immediately brought to the attention of the suppliers who initiated recalls."*

Comment: @MaxWilliams: even in software testing, the tranches are not all identical, and this seems to be true in the French use of the word as well.

Comment: A *tranche* in French is a slice taken from a larger object, like a loaf of bread. The action of slicing is done *after* the larger object has been prepared. If *tranche* is used figuratively in place of another collective term (group, batch, section, etc.), it has the connotation of being a “thin and flat” part taken from a larger whole. If your data can be organized this way, go ahead and use it. However, as a general term for a group of results, it sounds out of place.